# Conversion from string to 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

Updated Code: After turning on Option Strict On, as suggested, I am now receiving the following error: For both the tbMonday1 and tbMonday2 variables:
Option strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to String.
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversion from 'String' to 'Double'.
So something is definitely not working ....

```
Option Strict On

Dim TotalHour1, TotalHour2, TotalHour3, TotalHour4, TotalHour5, TotalHour6, TotalHour7, TotalHour8, TotalHour9, TotalHour10,
        TotalHour11, TotalHour12, TotalHour13, TotalHour14 As Double

Private Sub BtnTotalWages_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTotalWages.Click
    Dim m As Double

    Dim Emp1I = dtpDateIn1.Value.Date + dtpTimeIn1.Value.TimeOfDay   ' Employee 1 Arrival Date/Time
    Dim Emp1O = dtpDateOut1.Value.Date + dtpTimeOut1.Value.TimeOfDay ' Employee 1 Departure Date/Time

    Dim Emp2I = dtpDateIn2.Value.Date + dtpTimeIn2.Value.TimeOfDay   ' Employee 2 Arrival Date/Time
    Dim Emp2O = dtpDateOut2.Value.Date + dtpTimeOut2.Value.TimeOfDay ' Employee 2 Departure Date/Time

    Dim ts1 As TimeSpan = Emp1O.Subtract(Emp1I) ' Employee 1 Departure Date/Time - Employee 1 Arrival Date/Time to get elapsed time
    Dim ts2 As TimeSpan = Emp2O.Subtract(Emp2I) ' Employee 2 Departure Date/Time - Employee 2 Arrival Date/Time to get elapsed time

    'Convert a timespan to an absolute (positive) value for Time In / Time Out
    Dim Emp1In As Decimal = CDec(Math.Abs(ts1.TotalMinutes))
    Dim Emp2In As Decimal = CDec(Math.Abs(ts2.TotalMinutes))

    Dim Emp1Out As Decimal = CDec(Math.Abs(ts1.TotalMinutes))
    Dim Emp2Out As Decimal = CDec(Math.Abs(ts2.TotalMinutes))

    Dim TotalHours1 = ts1.ToString
    Dim TotalHours2 = ts2.ToString

    If rbMon.Checked = True Then
        lblHrsWorked1.Text = TotalHours1
        tbMonday1.Text = CDec(CStr(lblHrsWorked1.Text)) * tbHourlyRate1.Text) + (tbHourlyRate1.Text * tbOverTime1.Text))
        tbMonday1.Text = FormatCurrency(tbMonday1.Text)
        tbWagesPW1.Text = FormatCurrency(tbMonday1.Text)

        lblHrsWorked2.Text = TotalHours2
        tbMonday2.Text = CDec(CStr(lblHrsWorked2.Text)) * tbHourlyRate2.Text) + (tbHourlyRate2.Text * tbOverTime2.Text))
        tbMonday2.Text = FormatCurrency(tbMonday2.Text)
        tbWagesPW2.Text = FormatCurrency(tbMonday2.Text)

    ElseIf rbTue.Checked = True Then
        m = CDbl(tbWagesPW1.Text)
        lblHrsWorked1.Text = TotalHours1
        tbTuesday1.Text = CDec(CStr(lblHrsWorked1.Text)) * tbHourlyRate1.Text) + (tbHourlyRate1.Text * tbOverTime1.Text)
        tbTuesday1.Text = FormatCurrency(tbTuesday1.Text)
        tbWagesPW1.Text = FormatCurrency(tbTuesday1.Text)
        tbWagesPW1.Text = CStr(m + CDbl(tbTuesday1.Text))

        m = CDbl(tbWagesPW2.Text)
        lblHrsWorked2.Text = TotalHours2
        tbTuesday2.Text = CDec(CStr(lblHrsWorked2.Text)) * tbHourlyRate2.Text) + (tbHourlyRate2.Text * tbOverTime2.Text)
        tbTuesday2.Text = FormatCurrency(tbTuesday2.Text)
        tbWagesPW2.Text = CStr(m + CDbl(tbTuesday2.Text))

    ElseIf rbWed.Checked = True Then
        m = CDbl(tbWagesPW1.Text)
        lblHrsWorked1.Text = TotalHours1
        tbWednesday1.Text = CDec(CStr(lblHrsWorked1.Text * tbHourlyRate1.Text) + (tbHourlyRate1.Text * tbOverTime1.Text)
        tbWednesday1.Text = FormatCurrency(tbWednesday1.Text)
        tbWagesPW1.Text = FormatCurrency(tbWednesday1.Text)
        tbWagesPW1.Text = CStr(m + CDbl(tbWednesday1.Text))

        m = CDbl(tbWagesPW2.Text)
        lblHrsWorked2.Text = TotalHours2
        tbWednesday2.Text = CDec(CStr(lblHrsWorked2.Text * tbHourlyRate2.Text) + (tbHourlyRate2.Text * tbOverTime2.Text)
        tbWednesday2.Text = FormatCurrency(tbWednesday2.Text)
        tbWagesPW2.Text = CStr(m + CDbl(tbWednesday2.Text))

    End If

    tbWagesPW1.Text = FormatCurrency(tbWagesPW1.Text)
    tbWagesPW2.Text = FormatCurrency(tbWagesPW2.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: What does multiplying two strings mean in the attempted calculation `lblHrsWorked1.Text * tbHourlyRate1.Text`? You need to convert strings to numeric values to be able to multiply them.

Comment: If you set [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) then Visual Studio can point out problems like that for you.

Comment: Turned on 'Option Strict On.' It 'offered' the following changes: tbMonday1.Text = CStr(CDec(lblHrsWorked1.Text * tbHourlyRate1.Text) + (tbHourlyRate1.Text * tbOverTime1.Text)) but then shows all variables in the parenthesis as "Option Strict on disallows implicit conversion from 'String' to 'Double'. How do I fix this? I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps there are too many conversions needed for it to be happy with. However, now that you know the conversions must be done, you can do them yourself.

Comment: `Option Striict On` means that the system will not make assumptions or conversion about most data types so it's up to you to put some thought into what data should be being used and make any required casts or conversion. For example, as suggested above, multiplying strings is meaningless. A conversion needs to be done so you should be doing it, not leaving it to the system. You should know what type of numbers you want to multiply, e.g. `Integers` or `Doubles`, so you should be explicitly converting the input text to that type. You should also be validating user input.

Answer (score 0):

The kindest way to put this is as follows.
Put all those text fields containing values into `Double` variables.

```
Dim HrsWorked as Double : If Not Double.TryCast(lblHrsWorked1.Text, HrsWorked) then HrsWorked = 0
```

Then work with those variables to your hearts content. Display the result with `ToString()`

```
lblHrsWorked2.Text = HrsWorked.ToString()
```